# How do I return an element from an array with the largest specific value in it?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
array = [['A', '12', '12'], ['B', '12', '102']]

y = 1
for subarray in array:

    if subarray[2] > subarray[y][2]:
        print(subarray[0])

    y += 1
```

I wish to return the first element of the subarray with the highest final value (subarray[2]), in this example the program should return B because 102>12

Answer (score 2):

You could use `max` with a key to order based on the last element cast to `int`, and take the first element:

```
max(array, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))[0]
# 'B'
```